# writing lots of small amount of data to a file (like logging)

Tags: file, logging, operating-system, storage

I have a job that need to write lots of small amount of data individually to a file (like logging). If I implement it just like normal file write access, will that wear out my disk very quick?

I later realized the best solution depends on different systems too. In my case I can use ramdisk or such. But I wonder what is the solution for industry systems normally use, in case I want expandability.

Answer (score 0):

> But I wonder what is the solution for industry systems normally use

Filebeat was used to manage logging in one of my past project. As far as I remember, you need to do few settings in its config file. You need to specify the remote server and the file that you want to keep uploading.

filebeat will keep uploading your logs on that remote server.

You can read more about it: https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat

Comment: There are other solutions.  You should try harder to avoid looking 'spammy':)

Comment: @MartinJames. Oh well thanks for pointing it out :-). Actually filebeat was used in my last project where I was working. I think I should mention it differently.